# Could not pass parameter to UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have slightly different cells and for such purpose I need to pass parameter from my UIViewController to my subclass of UITableViewCell. But it does not work. The scenario is written as below:

MessagesViewController.m :

```
#import "MessagesViewController.h"
#import "MessageTableViewCell.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{    
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView registerClass:[MessageTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:MessengerCellIdentifier];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MessageTableViewCell *cell = (MessageTableViewCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MessengerCellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[MessageTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MessengerCellIdentifier customParam:YES];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

MessageTableViewCell.m :

```
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier customParam:(BOOL)customParam
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
       // **** GET Custom Parameter (customParam) HERE ??? ****/
    }
    return self;
}
```

At this scenario customParam is my parameter. Everything seems as OK, but cell is not nil and so the procedure fails.

Comment: What doesn't work? Your question isn't clear.

Comment: What parameter u tried to pass in to the table cell ?

Comment: Edited, thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option 1: Remove the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` line so that you create a new custom cell every time.  Otherwise you are using a pre-existing cell that already has the previous `customParameter` set to whatever the last cell displayed was set to.

-Note to option 1 (added as  explanation of why it is a very, VERY, **VERY** bad idea (@Duncan C).  Since you are setting up your cells with a `ReuseIdentifier` in creating your cells iOS will hold on to them for you once they scroll offscreen so that you can reuse them when your code asks for it.  But then your code never asks for reusable cells because it makes a completely new one each time the table asks for the next cell.  This causes high load times (to create a new cell every time) and high memory use (since the OS is saving the cells for you to use later and not deallocating them immediately).  The reusability was built for a reason, so don't use Option 1 unless you have very specific need to do so (and even then, you are probably wrong, don't do it).

Option 2: Change the custom parameter to a separate method call.  Instead of in the initializer create a new method that clears the cell and rebuilds it the way your new custom parameter requires.  Then you can re-use cells and modify their looks using the new `setCustomParameter:` method.

Edit:  Code example of option 2, as simple as possible:

In table controller

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MessageTableViewCell *cell = (MessageTableViewCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MessengerCellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[MessageTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MessengerCellIdentifier];
    }
    [cell setCustomParam:customParam];
    return cell;
}
```

In your cell .m

```
-(void)setCustomParam:(ParamType)type
{
    //Do whatever you would like right here to clear the previous
    //cell's custom information and add the new custom information
    //to this new cell.
}
```

Comment: Option 1 is BAD. Do not use Option 1. Option 2 is GOOD. Use Option 2.

Comment: @rmaddy I wouldn't call option 1 bad, just much much much much less gooder than option 2.

Comment: No, it's bad. You shouldn't bypass the standard table view cell reuse unless your table only has one or two rows.

Comment: I was about to write the same as rmaddy, but he beat me to it. So I'll repeat what he said for emphasis: Option 1 is a non-starter. Do not do this under any circumstances. Option 1 is very, VERY, **VERY** bad. The only circumstance where this is acceptable is if you know you will always create a small number of cells that will always fit on-screen and your table view will never scroll.

Comment: @DuncanC Added a note as to why Option 1 is bad.  But still left it there for completeness of answer...

Comment: @Putz1103 Could you please explain more about "option 2" in original codes? Thanks. I tested the option 1 earlier and it cause hight memory usage.

Comment: Updated the answer with a super simplistic example of option 2.

Answer (score 0):

Then you have to try some another method to add parameters in the MessageTableViewCell. The parameter is nil because the cell aren't nil everytime they are reusing the table view cell from the line

MessageTableViewCell *cell = (MessageTableViewCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MessengerCellIdentifier];

You have to call another method like

```
MessageTableViewCell *cell = (MessageTableViewCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MessengerCellIdentifier];

if (customParam)
{
// IF custom parameter is your labal
cell.yourCustomParameter.text = @"Add your content here"

}
```